# How to make Command binding to CheckBox in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, command

The problem is actually as stated in the title. If the `CheckBox`is outside, I can make a command binding as below and it works fine.

My `CheckBox` command binding doesn't work if I enclose it in a `ListView`. Also, when I create a `CheckBoxCommand` in the Model, there is no binding error, but I couldn't figure out how to use `CheckBoxCommand` in my Model.

```
<CheckBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckBoxCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

ViewModel

```
 public RelayCommand CheckBoxCommand { get; set; }

 public AnalysisViewModel()
 {
     CheckBoxCommand = new RelayCommand(CheckBoxClick);
 }

 private void CheckBoxClick(object param)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Click");
 }
```

It does not work in the following case. How can I run it with an application in the following situation?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding checkMessageList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding ID}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckBoxCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MyModel

```
public static readonly ObservableCollection<CanBusDataMessageResponse> checkMessageList = new ObservableCollection<CanBusDataMessageResponse>();

public class CanBusDataMessageResponse
{
    public int IDE { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public byte RTR { get; set; }
    public byte DLC { get; set; }
    public byte Byte0 { get; set; }
    public byte Byte1 { get; set; }
    public byte Byte2 { get; set; }
    public byte Byte3 { get; set; }
    public byte Byte4 { get; set; }
    public byte Byte5 { get; set; }
    public byte Byte6 { get; set; }
    public byte Byte7 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Up command binding my checkBox doesn't work if I enclose it in a listView.

If your `CheckBox` is defined in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView`, its `DataContext` is set to the item in the `checkMessageList` that it was created for, not to the data context of the `ListBox`.

Your original binding below expects a property `CheckBoxCommand` on items in the collection that is bound to `ItemSource`. If you add a command to your item model, this binding should work.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckBoxCommand}"/>
```

In order to bind to the `CheckBoxCommand` in the view model that is the data context of the `ListView` (and also contains `checkMessageList`) you can use a `RelativeSource` binding.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckBoxCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean. Connecting to the wrong spot caused the problem.